# Deployed jobs stopped working with an image error?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

In the last few hours I am no longer able to execute deployed Data Fusion pipeline jobs - they just end in an error state almost instantly.

I can run the jobs in Preview mode, but when trying to run deployed jobs this error appears in the logs:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Selected software image version '1.2.65-deb9' can no longer be used to create new clusters. Please select a more recent image
```

I've tried with both an existing instance and a new instance, and all deployed jobs including the sample jobs give this error.

Any ideas? I cannot find any config options for what image is used for execution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are currently investigating an issue with the image for Cloud Dataproc used by Cloud Data Fusion. We had pinned a version of Dataproc VM image for the launch that is causing an issue.

We apologize for you inconvenience. We are working to resolve the issue as soon as possible for you.

Will provide update on this thread.

Nitin

Comment: Hi Jamie,  This issues should be resolved by now. Can you please check it out when you get a chance.